# Start state for a DFA in Automata

Tags: regular-language, automata, state-machine

Suppose a DFA has to be designed which accept all string over Σ={0,1}* which start and ends with same symbol(e.g-0110,10101 etc.).Is ε a acceptable string ? Which means,Is start state a final state?

Comment: Is that the exact description of the language which should be accepted by the DFA? I would interpret the second condition as "the first symbol of the string is the same as the last symbol" — which emphasizes that the string has to contain a symbol, so it cannot be empty.

Comment: Yes that is the exact description of the language.

Comment: So,should i mark the initial state final?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what is meant. Human languages are vague and imprecise; that's why we invent formalisms like regular expressions in the first place.

If this is an exercise, I would ask whomever is giving you the exercise for clarification. On the surface, two interpretations seem reasonable:

- The empty string does not start and end with different letters, so it should not be excluded
- The empty string does not start and end with the same letter, so it should not be included

If it is an exercise and you have the original wording, you can provide a quote, but as stated, the answer is simply not clear. If homework, you could always provide two DFAs, one for each interpretation, with some discussion of the ambiguity.

If it is just a question you made up, then you will have to answer for yourself whether you want the empty string in your language.

Comment: But ε is a kind of hypothetical thinking in a way that,It contain nothing,and there is only one way to start and end for nothing.

Comment: Can you focus on the above comment?

Comment: @Hailey There may be other ways to think about the question - but there is at least one interpretation where the empty string is in the language, and at least one interpretation where it's not. Interpretations of the meaning of the empty string can be viewed as part of the interpretation of the question. I'm not sure I have more to add.

Answer (score 0):

YES.

The String ε belongs to {0,1}* and its start and end symbols are not different.So it should be accepted by the DFA